# Signup form in Django not showing checkboxinput as checkboxinput

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to add "Accept termns and conditions" to signup form in my Django project. As I did before in a different form I added this:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
 -> accept = forms.BooleanField(required=True, widget=CheckboxInput, label="I Accept the TNC!")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

It shows you this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnhJd.png)

I can not check it, I can not write in it. While in a different form I added the same way and that works normally. It is really weird for me, I am only a beginner to Django.

I tried with empty argument section like this:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
    accept = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Showing the same.

Comment: Do you by any chance tinker with the fields on a template level? If you change the form in forms.py but the form stays the same, the reason for it could be that in your_view.html you specifically overwrite the form logic.

Comment: Open the browser's inspector, use the inspect feature and select the input for the `accept` field. Copy the HTML rendered, edit your question and paste it so we can help you more.

Comment: Try to replace `{% render_field field class=field|input_class %}` with `{{ field }}` just to see if this is where your problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

if you are use **Bootstrap 5.3** then you need to add class attribute in **`CheckboxInput()`** your code becom like this...

#### form.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    accept = forms.BooleanField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-input'}), label="I Accept the TNC!" )
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2','accept']

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-5 p-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="">{{form.username.label}}</label>
        {{form.username}} 
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="">{{form.password1.label}}</label>
        {{form.password1}} 
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="">{{form.password2.label}}</label>
        {{form.password2}} 
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="">{{form.email.label}}</label>
        {{form.email}} 
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        {{form.accept}}
        <label class="form-check-label" >
          {{form.accept.label}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output

[image]